# How to align text on top of image and make it responsive?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Sorry am very new to HTML and CSS. I am trying to achieve a responsive lading page. I was able to display text on image by changing image style to relative and text style to absolute. However when I try to resize the site to mobile or tablet size the text goes under the second image.
Am not sure if I am doing anything wrong. Kindly advise.

Please advise what's the best approach to display text on image and make the site responsive?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <img class="bg_image"  src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg">
            <h2 class="Lorem_Headding">Lorem ipsum </h2>
            <p class="p-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam. Tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <img class="bg_image"  src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg">
            <h2 class="Lorem_Headding">Lorem ipsum </h2>
            <p class="p-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam. Tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.bg-image { 
    position: relative; 
  }

.Lorem_Headding{
  position: absolute; 
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  top: 200px; 
  left: 50px; 
  width: 100%;
}
.p-text{

    color: white;
    position: absolute; 
  top: 250px; 
  left: 50px; 
  width: 660px; 
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the image as the background of the div rather than setting it as a child element of the div?

Comment: first class="row" endtag is missing,

Comment: @Ortund Yes but that sets the background size based on the row size. How do I make the row size as the size of the background image?

Comment: @NIKHILCHANDRAROY sorry its a typo I've fixed it.

Comment: You should start by applying `position: relative` to a common wrapper element, so that the absolute positioning of any descendants takes that wrapper element as offset point, and not the viewport.

Comment: @CBroe the did apply the postion: relative to the container-fluid class which is the common wrapper for the row but yet row background size doesnt change according to the background size

Comment: What background? What background-size? You don't currently _have_ a background image, you are using a normal one. `background-size` does only work on background images.

Answer (score 0):

.p-text does not need the width: 660px;. the div should wrap the text. you can give the margin, padding for the better UI. for the responsive issue you can try using media query for each screen width.